# Which sensor to use for surrounding detection?

Tags: android, machine-learning, android-sensors, mfcc

I want to detect the surface on which my android phone is kept by vibrating the phone on the surface for few seconds(say 3) and using some machine learning features. Which sensor will the best to record data and why? I tried using the microphone to record the vibration sound and applied MFCC features on it but it didn't give good results.

Comment: The only sensor that can capture a sound on a mobile is actually a microphone. We still don't have ultrasound sensors. If it doesn't give the desired results... try changing your algorhithm

Comment: you probably gonna need that https://www.google.com/atap/projecttango/

Comment: Can you people please elaborate. Can't I use accelerometer sensor instead of microphones?

Comment: I have tried putting the MFCC features produced through neural network which didn't give good results. Is there any code implemented something like that available which could help me in any possible way?